# VLC seems to ignore the "cursor size" setting in Universal Access

Tags: 20.04, vlc, accessibility, mouse-pointer

Ubuntu 20.04LTS, VLC 3.0.10. I have set "Large" for the mouse cursor size, and I have not experience this problem with other applications but only on VLC, the cursor becomes really small. It seems to be smaller than the "default" size.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I actually experience the same problem with Netbeans that does not obey the configured cursor size. It is *very* uncomfortable on a 32 inch monitor. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-size` is `96` on my computer, and I am currently using 20.04.1 LTS (gnome is 3.36.3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. Read somewhere that this was an issue with all snap apps. So i installed VLC from [Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.videolan.VLC) and it is working fine now.

Comment: Yeah, This is an old question but after posting this I had solved this by removing the default Snap one and installing the native VLC.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with VLC and pycharm due to connecting second monitor. Solved by just close/open app.